# Совпадение конкретных символов Regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет, мне нужно чтобы совпадали конкретные символы
напрмиер
"ab" проходит проверку
"abababab" проходит
"aab, abb, abaa" не проходит

есть какие-то два символа которые должны идти друг за другом, например "xx" и подходить будет строка где n-ое количество раз чередуются эти 2 символа, в случае если затисался какой то другой символ то строка не подходит, если только один символ присутствует то тоже не подходит

Comment: Уточни, по какому принципу ты решаешь, что одна строка подходит, а другая нет

Comment: передаем строку "123qweab" не подходит  передаем "ab" подходит, передаем "abab" подходит

Comment: А почему "abababab"  подходит?

Comment: есть какие-то два символа которые должны идти друг за другом, например "xx" и подходить будет строка где n-ое количество раз чередуются эти 2 символа, в случае если затисался какой то другой символ то строка не подходит, если только один символ присутствует то тоже не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строка подходит только если она состоит из повторений первых двух символов:

```
^(.)(.)(\1\2)*$
```

Проверка

```js
function check(s) {
  return /^(.)(.)(\1\2)*$/.test(s)
}

console.log(["ab", "abababab"].every(check))
console.log(["aab", "abb", "abaa"].every(s => !check(s)))
```